# The LINQ expression could not be translated. how to avoid client evaluation in given query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Data size is too large so I can't apply tolist  on my object.

Is there any way to avoid client side evaluation in below query?

```cs
return new AuthRight<ABCContainerDto<List<QTypeDto>>>
{

    Item = new ABCContainerDto<List<QTypeDto>>
    {
        Proj = _mapperService.MapToDto<Proj, EstimationDto>(proj),
        Data = _context.Quant
            .Where(x => x.EstimationID.Equals(estimation.ID))
            .DistinctBy(x => x.QuantTypeID)
            .Select(x => x.QuantType.MapToDto())
            .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
            .ToList()
    },
    AccessLevel = projectAccessLevel.MapToDto()
};
```

Error

> The LINQ expression '`DbSet<Quantity>() .Where(x => x.EstimationID.Equals(__estimation_ID_0)) .DistinctBy(x => x.QuantityTypeID)`' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: There is nothing in your question that even relates to ASP.NET Core, never mind exclusively to it. Tag removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in this query:

- `DistinctBy` is not translatable by EF Core
- `MapToDto` - if this extension method is not backed by extension library which expands Expression Tree, like `LINQKit`, `Delegate Decompiler`, etc. You cannot use `OrderBy` after `Select`. EF Core cannot look into compiled method body and understand how fields are mapped to database.

```cs
_context.Quant
    .Where(x => x.EstimationID == estimation.ID)
    .GroupBy(x => x.QuantTypeID)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.QuantType).First())
    .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
    .Select(x => x.MapToDto())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GroupBy()` and `OrderBy` to get rid of `DistinctBy()` and client-side evaluation perf issues.

```
 Data = context.Quant
.Where(x => x.EstimationID.Equals(estimation.ID))
.GroupBy(x => x.QuantTypeID)
.Select(g => g.First().QuantType.MapToDto())
.OrderBy(x => x.Code)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Mapping to DTO with following `OrderBy` makes this query non translatable.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You are right. Updated the code.